# Using FST libraries in Python

Tags: python, nlp, state-machine, openfst, fst

**How do I install [OpenFST](http://www.openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/FST/WebHome)?**

I have been doing it as such:

```
wget http://www.openfst.org/twiki/pub/FST/FstDownload/openfst-1.4.1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf openfst-1.4.1.tar.gz
cd openfst-1.4.1
./configure
make
make install
```

**Is there any other way to install this?**

Actually what I eventually wanted is to use OpenFST in Python, I've been using this wrapper: https://github.com/vchahun/pyfst

After installing `OpenFST`, when installing `pyfst`, I had the following problem. Anyone knows how to resolve that?:

```
$ sudo pip install pyfst
 ....

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/pyfst/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-O7BSyr-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/pyfst
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.5', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.5.5-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.5.5-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 42: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**But is there a pure Python port of OpenFST?**

Comment: The error message basically means you don't have `gcc` installed.

Answer (score 4):

Since OpenFST 1.5 was released it now includes a Python wrapper.  In 1.5.3 that wrapper is much more full-featured than the handful of independent OpenFST Python wrappers.  I don't know of any pure-python FST implementations.  There certainly aren't any well-known ones at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I've found one pure Python FST that's [PyFoma](https://github.com/mhulden/pyfoma) and it seems to have the same functionalities as OpenFST. Quoting from their docs:

> #### PyFoma
>
> PyFoma is a an open source (Apache) package for finite-state automaton and transducer modeling and learning. **It is implemented entirely in Python with no external dependencies.**